# Proof of X is not Banach

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, cauchy-sequences

Set $X = \lbrace u\in\mathcal{C}^2 [0,\pi]: u(0)=u(\pi)=0\rbrace$ equipped with the norm $$\Vert u \Vert = \left(\int_0^\pi (u'(x))^2\ dx + \int_0^\pi u(x)^2\ dx\right)^{1/2}$$

I want to prove that $(X,\Vert \cdot \Vert)$ is not complete. Can anyone give me a hint or some ideas to find a Cauchy sequence in $X$ that is not convergent in $\Vert \cdot \Vert$-norm to any element of $X$?. I spent a lot of time thinking but I couldn't find one.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to approximate something like $u(x)=\pi/2-|\pi/2-x|$.

Comment: this works? $$ u_n (x)= -\sqrt{(\pi / 2 - x)^2+1/n} +\sqrt{\pi^2/4+1/n} $$

Comment: I was right: the sequence from above is Cauchy in $(X,\Vert \cdot \Vert )$ and it is not hard to prove that if $u_n$ is convergent then it must converge (in $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ - norm) to the function $u(x) = \pi / 2 - \vert \pi / 2 -x \vert$ which clearly does not belong to $X$.